# JSTL inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jstl

I'm creating tabs dynamically in bootstrap tabs using jQuery. This is triggered with an event

To more clear look here is what I'm doing:

```
$('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_' + id + '">  </div>');
```

Now inside the `<div>` I'm going to write a long `HTML` so I thought that it could be messy if I write all the code in the jQuery. So I decided to make an external file and import it using `JSTL` and write the import inside the jQuery code:

```
$('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_' + id + '"> <c:import url="flt-pis.html"></c:import> </div>');
```

The `<c:import url="flt-pis.html"></c:import>` of JSTL seems not working, I don't know why. Is there an other way around?

Comment: You need to run your application on servlet container/app server in order for JSTL to work - are you doing this? You can probably use jquery load function since the page seems to be on the same domain. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Zyga Thanks for the response. Im quite a newbie in jQuery so, Can you give me a clear view of what your trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

jstl is run server side. javascript client. This won't work.

You can reference jstl inside embedded javascript with  in your jsp page- the text is output to the js on server side.

Comment: Is there any work around with this? I just want to place the rest of the code outside the `.js` file it self.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before you cannot run JSTL on client side.

Given that the page is on the same domain (and by the sound of it, it is) you can use jQuery "load" function to put HTML from external file in your newly created div.

for example, after you execute this

```
$('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_' + id + '">  </div>');
```

you can then do this:

```
$("#tab_"+id).load("flt-pis.html");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I added that exactly next after the appending the `tab-pane`. It doesn't load the page.